# GWT CSS syntax not working properly

Tags: java, jquery, css, gwt, gwtquery

In the GWT tutorial page [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/CssGuide), it clearly says near the bottom of the page that the user is not restricted to the type safe declarations, he can use jQuery syntax also. I have a textbox defined in my GWT, to which I add a class `foo` after generation by the `setStyleName` method. Afterwards, when I try to attach style like:

```
$(".foo").css($$("border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; border-radius: 5px; font-size: 80%; padding: 6px 3px 4px 3px;  text-align: center;\r\n" + 
            "    -moz-transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.2s linear 0s;\r\n" + 
            "    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset; background: #f1f1f1; margin: 20px 50px;"));
```

it doesn't work at all, I just get a bland textbox. However the styles apply perfectly fine when I define the styles in the CSS file. What is wrong here?

Comment: Perfectly added the gQuery jars ?

Comment: Yeah, everything is working fine save this.

Comment: you sure that the .class isn't changed to something that look like XFEAFSF (random name) by gwt?

Comment: What is that? And how do I check it?

Comment: in your browser check the html if the class of the textbox is .foo, if its set by a clientbundle the classname might change...

Comment: Yeah checked in Firebug. It is.

Comment: Isn't it because of your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400401/no-gwtquery-function-is-working

Comment: No. even after adding it after the `RootPanel.get()...`, it is not working...

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the element exists in the DOM when you fire your jquery call,
try a simple case and make sure you have the syntax correct.

```
$(".foo").css($$("border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; background-color: #ffe;"));
```

Comment: You better delete this answer, or it is going to be flooded with down votes. You are talking about jQuery. GWTQuery is similar, but in Java, so it is completely different. This example is a JS example, it will totally fail in GWT!

Comment: Updated with gquery syntax.  The important thing to verify is that the gquery call happens after the element is in the dom and the class name is set.  Anyways, good luck.